# Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported SpringBoot Rest

Tags: json, spring, rest, content-type

I have this exception when I'm trying to send POST or PUT request on RestController
[image]
I don't use Jackson which solve all other similar problem on SOF.
Controller:
`    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class UserController {

```
private final UserService userService;

@PutMapping
@Validated(UserDto.OnUpdate.class)
public void save(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    User user = UserMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(userDto);
    userService.save(user);
}

@PostMapping
@Validated(UserDto.OnCreate.class)
public UserDto create(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    User userToBeCreated = UserMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(userDto);
    User user = userService.create(userToBeCreated);
    return UserMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(user);
}
}`
```

UserDto:
`    @Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password", "passwordConfirmation"})
public class UserDto {

```
@Null(message = "Id must be null", groups = {OnCreate.class})
@NotNull(message = "Id must not be null", groups = {OnUpdate.class})
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "Name is required", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
@Length(min = 3, max = 45, message = "Username must be between {min} and {max} characters", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "Email is required", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
@Length(min = 3, max = 45, message = "Email must be between {min} and {max} characters", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
@Email(message = "Email must be valid")
private String email;

@NotNull(message = "Phone number is required", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
@Length(min = 3, max = 45, message = "Phone number must be between {min} and {max} characters", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
private String phoneNumber;

@NotNull(message = "Password is required", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
@Length(min = 6, message = "Password must be longer than {min} characters", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
private String password;

@NotNull(message = "Password confirmation is required", groups = {OnCreate.class})
@Length(min = 6, message = "Password confirmation must be longer than {min} characters",    groups = {OnCreate.class})
private String passwordConfirmation;

private List<AddressDto> addresses;

private List<OrderDto> orders;

private CartDto cart;

private LocalDate createdAt;

public interface OnCreate {
}

public interface OnUpdate {
}
}`
```

User:
`    @Data
public class User {

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String passwordConfirmation;
private String phoneNumber;
private List<Address> addresses;
private List<Order> orders;
private Cart cart;
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}`
```

I have similar requests which is working, but difference in User has other objects inside, so I think problem is in it.

I've tried to debug and remove validation annotations, but this request does not go into method.

As I mentioned, `@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")` does not work. I have this exception because I have refs on other classes, but they don't need to be validated, but If i remove code with another classes it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is in `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` annotation above fields of other classes. It makes to avoid validation when I send a request to server

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot definitely supports Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'. Just chenge your annotation `@PostMapping` to `@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")` See [Spring @GetMapping and @PostMapping article](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/controller-getmapping-postmapping/) for detailed explanation with examples

Comment: As I mentioned, It does not work. I have this exception because I have refs on other classes, but they don't need to be validated, but If i remove code with another classes it works

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused by something else.

In my case i was using an `@Entity` annotated class as an `@RequestBody` type as well. This class contains one @OneToMany collection field that i forgot to annotate with `@JsonIgnore`. This caused spring to throw the error `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported` when i tried to make a post request. This is very misleading because spring boot accepts `application/json` content types by default. Annotating the collection field with @JsonIgnore fixed my problem.